# SSIS Derived column Replace expression

Tags: replace, ssis

I'm using the replace function to replace string (formula) Var(A) by the column (value) AM01, Var(B) by BM01, up to Var(E), but let's stick to A and B for now.
AM01 = 4
BM01 = 5

The first replacement works fine, this is because Var(A) is in every formula.

```
     REPLACE(M01,(DT_WSTR,100)"Var(A)",(DT_WSTR,100)AM01)
```

Result:

```
Var(A) = 4
Var(A)/Var(B) = 4/Var(B)
```

When i have a second derived column after this one with formula

```
     REPLACE(M01,(DT_WSTR,100)"Var(B)",(DT_WSTR,100)BM01)
```

It goes badly depending on the formula:

```
Var(A) = NULL
Var(A)/Var(B) = 4/5
```

I read up on this and it seems that if the REPLACE function doesn't find a match it gives NULL, i want it to do nothing if no match, leave the original value.

Any suggestions? I can't go replacing in SQL unfortunately, lots of packages are run before coming to this point and writing to a DB for doing this update would cost a lot of time, and would require a temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the tertiary IIF function:

```
Something == Null ? (Return the original value) : (Return the formula(value))
```

The above is obviously pseudo code.

Comment: Simple, yet working. I used following expressions to workaround:

     FINDSTRING(M01,"Var(A)",1) > 0 ? (REPLACE(M01,(DT_WSTR,100)"Var(A)",(DT_WSTR,100)AM01)) : (DT_WSTR,100)AM01

And for Var B and more a little change at the end:

    FINDSTRING(M01,"Var(B)",1) > 0 ? (REPLACE(M01,(DT_WSTR,100)"Var(B)",(DT_WSTR,100)BM01)) : M01